# Can't access to data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, authentication

i sended data from postman with a post in body, with all the data that my model need, in my method "Register" the data is "saved" with any problem, but when i try to access to my data with a "Login" method the data is null.

This is my User model:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mSchema = mongoose.Schema; 


var mUserSchema = mSchema({
  name:String,
  nickname:String,
  email:String,
  password:String,
  image:String,
  role:String
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("Usuario", mUserSchema);
```

i sended all this data in postman and the result it's OK, the data is saved and i used this Register Method:

```
exports.guardarUsuario = function (req, res){ 

var mUser = new User(); 
var mParams = req.body; 

console.log(mParams);


mUser.name = mParams.name;
mUser.nickname = mParams.nickname;
mUser.email = mParams.email;
mUser.image = "null";
mUser.role = "ROLE_USER";


if(mParams.password){
    mBcrypt.hash(mParams.password, null, null, function(err, hash){
        mUser.password = hash;
        if(mUser.name != null && mUser.nickname != null && mUser.email != null){

            mUser.save((err, userStored) => { 
                if(!err){
                    if(!userStored){
                        res.status(404).send({message:"Este objeto no existe"});
                    }else{
                        res.send({user:userStored});
                    }
                }else{
                    res.status(500).send({message:"No se pudieron guardar los datos"});
                }
            });
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({message:"Introduce todos los campos"});
        }
    });
}else{
    res.status(200).send({message:"Introduce the password"});
}
```

}

I used this method to access to the data with this "Login" method:

```
exports.loginUsuarios = function(req, res){

var mParams = req.body;

var mEmail = mParams.email;
var mPassword = mParams.password;

User.findOne({mEmail: mEmail.toLowerCase(), mPassword: mPassword.toLowerCase()}, (err, user)=>{
    if(err){
        res.status(500).send({message:"Error en la peticion"});
    }else{
        if(user){

            mBcrypt.compare(mPassword, user.password, (err, check)=>{
                if(check){

                    if(mParams.gethash()){
                         //...                            
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).send({user: userStored});
                    }
                }else{

                }
            });
        }else if(!user){
            if(user == null){
                res.send({message: "No exite usuario"});
            }                          
        }
    }
});
}
```

When i try put the data with the correct email and pasword i for did the search i just give Null user object

Comment: `mParams.password;` is not "hashed". You need to do the same "hashing" in order to compare. So `mPassword: mPassword.toLowerCase()` is not the same as what you stored.

Comment: Why you set password lower case (mPassword: mPassword.toLowerCase()) ? If password in database had uppercase characters so when you compare with lowercase password , it completely wrong !

Comment: @everyBit, you have the reason i removed this

Comment: This is why i use the function Bcrypt.compare @NeilLunn

Comment: the password you stored in db must hashed and look like (#@EDASD@#ASD@#EASADS#@SAD) , right ? so if you're trying to compare the password that you stored with password from mParams.password, It's wrong too.

Comment: You are not using it in the `findOne()` though, which is the line of code being highlighted as the problem. Even if you were doing the "crypt" on the "client" before sending the request ( which would be advsied ) the "lowercase" conversion would still not be valid.

Comment: Ok I gonna try decrypt after to find

Comment: Well good luck with that. [how to decrypt this password hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635159/how-to-decrypt-this-password-hash). This is one of those times you need to accept when people are telling you that you're doing it wrong.