# How can i decrypt a password in laravel using decrypt()?

Tags: laravel, encryption, passwords

how can i decrypt a password?

I have this code, but returns me the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ0x7.jpg

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class AccountController extends Controller
{

      public function index(){

        $password = \Auth::user()->password;
        $passdecript = decrypt($password);

        return view('account', compact('passdecript'));

   }

}
```

Comment: How are you encrypting your password?

Comment: Or, a better question, **why** are you encrypting passwords?

Comment: You can't decrypt your password in any app. Password is private. You cand fine detail in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16636718/8071577)

Comment: How can i encrypt a varible? $actualpass = $request->input('actualpass');
     $actualcrypt = encrypt($actualpass); i have this. ¿If i encrypt the same password 2 times, will be the same encryption string?

Answer (score 2):

Passwords are hashed, not encrypted. Hashed is one way, That means they can’t be reversed into their plain text form. This is for security reasons.

If someone downloads your database, they shouldn’t be able to reverse each of your users’ passwords. It’s also a security issue to simply display a password back to the user in case they’re on an insecure network and someone is eavesdropping on the connection.

If you need to display a password, then you’re doing something wrong.